# JHipster - Running application inside a context, Image and Glyphicons problems

Tags: gruntjs, jhipster

I have a project generated with JHipster and would like to deploy it inside a context in Tomcat (not at root context).

There seems to be grunt task to change image and font to use a full path in the css. (cssmin)

I have found this [link](http://ignaciosuay.com/how-to-avoid-grunt-build-not-loading-bootstrap-glyphicons-using-jhipster/) to remove the cssmin but did not succeed in preventing this problem.

I'm searching a way to continue using the same task (cssmin) and be able to deploy a JHipster app in any way possible (as Tomcat root context or in a context /jhipster).

Comment: can you elaborate a bit further, If i understand your question correct, you mean to say that when you deploy a Jhipster app as a war to tomcat deploy folder it doesnt work? your question is not clear. I have deployed these manually to tomcat and didnt have any issues

Comment: And also cssmin does this only in prod profile, so you can check if it works with dev profile to confirm

Comment: For time being you can manually update the generated css files like this replace /bower_components with ../../bower_components and /assets with ../../assets

Comment: This is not a permanent solution though

Comment: How did you deploy to a different context on tomcat? Whenever i run 'mvn' it always deploys to tomcat root. How can i set a context?

Answer (score 0):

The current master branch contains a fix for this. If you can't wait for the next release you need to modify your `Gruntfile.js`.

First: Make `cssmin` use relative paths by **removing** the option `root: 'src/main/webapp'`

Second: You need a seperate copy task to copy the required fonts into the correct directory:

```
copy: {
        fonts: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                flatten: true,
                cwd: 'src/main/webapp',
                dest: '<%%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/fonts',
                src: [
                  'bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/*.*'
                ]
            }]
        }
```

Third: Add the new copy task to the build task by adding `'copy:fonts'` to the build tasks.